# Excel VBA Function Error "Application Defined or object defimed error"

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

```
Function GetInfoview(InfoviewID As String)

On Error GoTo ErrMsg

 Dim objRequest As Object
Dim strUrl As String
Dim blnAsync As Boolean
Dim strResponse As String
Dim JsonObj As String
Dim Jsondata As String
Dim ws As Worksheet


Dim i As Long
Dim ID As String
ID = InfoviewID


Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")



strUrl = "API URL"

blnAsync = True

With objRequest
    .Open "GET", strUrl, False
    
    .Send
    
    Dim response As String
response = objRequest.ResponseText
    
End With
  Set JsonObj = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
  Set Jsondata = JsonObj("InfoviewData")
  
  
  Dim activeRow As Integer
  Dim activeColumn As Integer
  
  activeRow = ActiveCell.Row
  activeColumn = ActiveCell.Column
  
  
  Set ws = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
 ws.Cells(activeRow, activeColumn) = JsonObj("Name")
 
 ws.Cells(activeRow + 1, activeColumn) = "Name"
 ws.Cells(activeRow + 1, activeColumn + 1) = "Description"
 ws.Cells(activeRow + 1, activeColumn + 2) = "Units"
 ws.Cells(activeRow + 1, activeColumn + 3) = "Value"
 i = activeRow + 2
 For Each Item In JsonObj("InfoviewData")
 ws.Cells(i, activeColumn) = Item("Name")
 ws.Cells(i, activeColumn + 1) = Item("Description")
 ws.Cells(i, activeColumn + 2) = Item("Units")
 ws.Cells(i, activeColumn + 3) = Item("currentValue")("Value")
 i = i + 1
 Next
 
'ActiveCell.Formula = "=GetInfoview(""41462"")"
 


 
Done:

Exit Function
ErrMsg:
MsgBox "There seems to be an error" & vbCrLf & Err.Description

End Function
```

I am getting this error in ws.Cell function. please tell me how to resolve this. Am i doing correct way or not.

Comment: Comment out the `On Error GoTo ErrMsg`: what line throws the error then?

Comment: Are you able to retrieve your JSON object with `JsonObj("Name")`? Try to debug that before. OT: If for some reason you are using the active cell, why to set the sheet and its address? Just write directly there

Comment: ws.Cells(activeRow, activeColumn) = JsonObj("Name")

this line throws the error

Comment: JsonObj("Name") Yes it is giving

Comment: What does `Debug.Print TypeName(JsonObj("Name"))` give you?

Comment: String returing

Comment: What if you instead use `ActiveCell.Value = JsonObj("Name")` ?

Comment: But I need to print all the data 

       ws.Cells(activeRow + 1, activeColumn) = "Name"
       ws.Cells(activeRow + 1, activeColumn + 1) = "Description"
 ws.Cells(activeRow + 1, activeColumn + 2) = "Units"
 ws.Cells(activeRow + 1, activeColumn + 3) = "Value"
 i = activeRow + 2
 For Each Item In JsonObj("InfoviewData")
 ws.Cells(i, activeColumn) = Item("Name")
 ws.Cells(i, activeColumn + 1) = Item("Description")
 ws.Cells(i, activeColumn + 2) = Item("Units")
 ws.Cells(i, activeColumn + 3) = Item("currentValue")("Value")

Comment: ActiveCell.Value = JsonObj("Name") 
This one also thows an error

Comment: Function inside that cell concept will work ?